# If $F\subseteq\mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb{Q})$, then $[F:\mathbb Q]\leq n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, field-theory

> Let $F$ be a field contained in the ring of $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb Q$. Prove that $[F:\mathbb Q]\leq n$.

I have an idea to consider a degree $n$ extension $K$ of $\mathbb Q$ and left multiplication of elements of $K$ by themselves is a $\mathbb Q$-linear transform so we get an isomorphic copy of $K$ and hence has degree $n$ over $\mathbb Q$ in matrix ring... but why don't we have larger subfields?

Answer (score 4):

Note that $F$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, since necessarily $[F:\mathbb{Q}]\leq n^2$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ has characteristic $0$, this finite extension is simple, by the primitive element theorem. So $F=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in M_n(\mathbb{Q})$. You can bound the degree of the minimal polynomial $m_\alpha$ above by $n$ by Cayley-Hamilton.